# Time Series Forecasting by Group in R

Tags: r, loops, time-series, forecasting

I have time series data grouped by U.S. state from 2008-2018 and I need to forecast values for 2019-2020. I tested the forecasting on Arizona and wrote something like this:

```
az <- subset(full_df, full_df$state == "AZ")

az$year <- lubridate::ymd(az$year, truncated = 2L)
az <- xts(az$variable, az$year)

forecast <- forecast(az, level = c(95), h = 2)
```

This works, producing two point estimates and their CIs.

My only issue is looping this over the entire original dataframe and producing the estimates for each state. Does anyone know how I would go about this?

Comment: What is `df`? Did you mean `full_df` or `az`?

Comment: My apologies, I think I made some typos in the original post but have since fixed them. full_df refers to the initial dataframe with all states. az is the dataframe with only az observations from 2000-2018. I use xts() on az to transform the dataframe into a time series object and then use forecast to predict values for 2019-20. The question, then, is how to do what I did to az over full_df for each state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a function, split and apply. I have not tested this as you did not include any data,

```
my_forecast_fun(df){
  df$year <- lubridate::ymd(df$year, truncated = 2L)
  df <- xts(df$variable, df$year)
  my_forecast <- forecast(df, level = c(95), h = 2) # avoid naming objects the same as functions (i.e. forecast)
  return(my_forecast)
}

my_list <- split(full_df, full_df$state)

res <- lapply(my_list, my_forecast_fun)
```

`res` is a list with the forecast for each state